# Maximal separable subalgebras of semisimple algebras

Tags: associative-algebras, separable-algebras

Is anything known about maximal separable subalgebras of semisimple algebras in finite-dimension? Are those subalgebras of unique dimension or isomorphic or conjugate?

Comment: Just to be certain, you are also considering non-commutative separable subalgebras, am I right?

Comment: Yes arbitrary separable subalgebras in finite dimensional associative semisimple algebras over fields

Comment: But of course also anwers are welcome for Special types of semi-simple algebras (which rae of course not separable).

Comment: we should close the topic.